# Loop with insert queries break after 8th iteration

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have a script which one pare some data from web page and insert this data to two MySQL tables. But each time my loop broke after 8th loop. I mean script inser 8 new rows and script finished with exit code 0. After `select movie_id from movie;` I've got 99 rows in `rows` variable but insert only 8 elements. Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="...", user="...", passwd="...", db="...")
cursor = db.cursor()

def parse_person(actor_id, movie_id):
    actor = # ...

    sql_insert_actor = """INSERT IGNORE INTO actor (name)
        values ("{0}");""".format(actor.name)
    sql_insert_tv_actor_mapping = """insert ignore into movie_actor_mapping (actor_id, movie_id) values ("{0}", "{1}");""".format(
            cursor.lastrowid,
            movie_id
        )
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_actor)
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_tv_actor_mapping)
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()


def parse_persons(actors_list, movie_id):
    for actor in actors_list:
        parse_person(actor.actor_id, movie_id)

try:
    cursor.execute('select movie_id from movie;')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        movie_id = row[0]
        actors_list = # parse some 
        parse_persons(actors_list, movie_id)
except:
    db.rollback()


db.close()
```

Comment: Remove the blanket `except:` statements and see what exception you get.

Comment: Next, replace the `try:...except` with `with db as cursor:` to roll back on exception *without* hiding the exception (the transaction will be committed if there is no exception).

Comment: Also, don't use `str.format()`. Use SQL parameters instead. You most likely have meta characters in your inputs and thus are producing invalid SQL.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you very much, it's helped me!